# calculate forecast for next 18 months on last extract date in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to check forecast quantity for next 18 months based on last extract date(every monday).If the last extract date is in march 2018,it should calculate next 18 months from march 2018.

I have tried below case statement in bigquery but it should take last monday date as extract date(extract_date) and provide sum of quantity for next 6,12,18 months based on material name(material) and delivery date(deliv_date)

```
SELECT
  material,
  material_desc,
  extract_date, 
  deliv_date,
  SUM(quantity) AS quantity, 
  CASE
      WHEN 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=1 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=2 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=3 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=4 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=5 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=6 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=7 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) THEN '6months' 

      WHEN 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=1 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=2 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=3 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=4 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=5 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=6 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=7 AND year(deliv_date)=2018 ) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=8 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=9 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=10 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=11 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) OR 
      (MONTH(deliv_date)=12 AND year(deliv_date)=2018) THEN '12Months' 
and same code for 18 months...
      ELSE NULL END AS Forecast_18_months 
      FROM table 
      GROUP BY
      material,
      material_desc,
      extract_date,
      deliv_date,
      Forecast_18_months
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough idea. Please refer to Bigquery SQL guide and modify it to fit your use case.

```
SELECT
  material
  forcast
  SUM(quantity)
FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    material
    CASE 
      WHEN DATE_DIFF(deliv_date, extract_date, MONTH) <= 6 THEN '6months'
      ELSE 'blabla'
    END AS forecast
    quantity
  FROM
    table
  )
GROUP BY
  material
  forecast
```

Comment: How can we calculate date diff for 18 months?

Comment: Just add more WHEN statement to check different cases up to 18 months.